# Removing an item from dictionary in Py3 during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

First of all I am trying to update my code from Python 2 to Python 3.
I am trying to update a Dictionary, I am updating the name of the keys, and poping out that keys that I don't use.
I am getting an error:
dictionary changed size during iteration

Code Example:

```
for k, v in self.v_signals.items():
    for jj in self.On_Signal_Option["levels_run"]:
        new_key = str(k) + str(jj)
        self.v_signals[new_key] = self.v_signals[k]
    self.v_signals.pop(k, None)
```

Comment: build a new dictionary instead of modifying the existing one

Comment: You almost never want to mutate the datastructure you're iterating on during the iteration, regardless of the programming language you're using. Take the advice in the first comment - it will save you time & pain!

Comment: @alfasin, I tend to agree with you, but sometimes you don't want to overload with so many duplicated/similar variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2):

The `items` method has changed between Python 2 and 3. In Python2, it builds a list while in Python3 it just gives an iterator on the dictionary (what `iteritems` did in Python2). So the correspondance 2 -> 3, when d is a `dict` is:

- d.items() -> list(d.items())
- d.iteritems() -> d.items()

This explains why the code worked in Python2 and no longer works in Python3.

So to keep Python 2 behaviour, you have to explicitely build an independant list:

```
for k, v in list(self.v_signals.items()):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

this will create a new dictionary.

```
self.v_signals = {
    str(k) + str(jj): v
    for k, v in self.v_signals.items()
    for jj in self.On_Signal_Option["levels_run"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the items to a list for iteration

```
for k, v in list(self.v_signals.items()):
  for jj in self.On_Signal_Option["levels_run"]:
      new_key = str(k)+str(jj)
      self.v_signals[new_key] = self.v_signals[k]
  self.v_signals.pop(k, None)
```